# Django: Adding a non-model field into serializers.serialize

Tags: json, django, django-models, django-queryset, django-serializer

I have following code:

```
pending_invoices=invoice.objects.filter(user=request.user,customer=pk).annotate(sum_invoices=Sum('invoicereceipt__amount'))
    pending_invoice=pending_invoices.filter(~Q(sum_invoices=0))
    invoices=serializers.serialize('json', pending_invoice,fields=("number","sum_invoices"))
    return HttpResponse(invoices,content_type='application/json')
```

I am trying to get JSON data through ajax.
I can successfully get `number` field in my output. But I have annotated `sum_invoices` and do not get this value in json output.

My question is whether my above code is correct if not then how do I add annotated field and result to my json output?

Edit:

```
invoices=serializers.serialize('json', pending_invoice,fields=("number","sum_invoices"))
```

In this above line `"number"` is a field in my model and `sum_invoices` I have added by using annotate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just got the solution. I am using `serializers.serialize` and it converts model to json data and does not consider any field other than present in model.

So best way to use is `json.dumps`

Here is the working code.

```
invoices = json.dumps(list(pending_invoice), cls=DjangoJSONEncoder)
```